# Javascript memory concerns and deleting unused variables

Tags: javascript

Assume that I have a code that like many other code utilizes many variables and assignments. If at the end of the script I set all unused variables to null, does it help memory and performance?

For instance, the following code:

```
function DoSomething ()
{
/**** do something ...... */
            if(emailValidator.test(allEmails) == 1) // #id.class.class.class
            {
                var email_parts = [];
                var i = 0;
                var tmp;
                while(tmp = emailValidator.exec(allEmails))
                {
                    email_parts[i] = tmp;
                    i++;
                }
                var wrapped_emails= "";
                for(w=0; w < emails_parts.length; w++)
                {
                    this_class = emails_parts[w][1];
                    emails_classes += " " + this_email.replace(/^\./, "") + " ";
                }
                emails_classes = emails_classes.trim();

                return emails_classes;

                tmp=null; email_parts = null; i = 0; // DOES THIS LINE HELPS THE MEMORY AND PERFORMANCE??????
            }

/** the rest ...... */
}// end of the function
```

If you see, near the end of the condition I have set all the variables to null, except the one which is to be returned.

Now, my question, does this ruling out variables to null helps the memory and performance of the execution?

Comment: I'm not sure that line even gets executed as you've done the `return` already. And those variables _are_ used.

Answer (score 0):

Setting variables to `null` just cause them to have the `null` value.

JavaScript has a garbage collector, which means that it will free variables that are not being referenced anymore (you might want to read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)).

In your case, though you declared both `tmp` and `email_parts` inside your `if` block, they will actually be deallocated in the end of the `DoSomething` function execution because those declarations are moved to the top of the scope (see [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)).

Also, as @Andy stated, `tmp=null; email_parts = null; i = 0;` has no effect since you put `return emails_classes;` right above it.

Answer (score 0):

## No it doesn't

As a programmer you shouldn't think about micro-tweaks like this. Let the compiler / garbage collector handle that.

Our main focus as a programmer should be 'easy to understand' code that 'does what it should'.

After you have finished writing your code. You can have a lookt at performance if it is an issue. If so, test, test, test and test